# Microsoft Store Pre-Certification AppCompile.exe

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-store

Recently we had an issue with submitting our UWP app into the Microsoft Store. We were getting a "mystical" error code: 1201. There is no further information on the support forums about this error. If there is any, it states that this error indicates failure on Microsoft Store servers but it's not always the case.

However, after contacting Store Support, we've got back log from Pre-Certification phase that was mentioning some "F:\AppCompileSdk\AppCompile\2.2\AppCompile.exe" - which was running into the error.

Is the **AppCompileSdk** publicly available? If yes, where can we get it?

Comment: Did you select ARM64 architecture when you package your app? If it is, could you please try not to select this architecture, package your app and upload it again? There used to be a similar case and this is the reason for that case.

Comment: That was one of the my ideas too - we were slightly experimenting with ARM64 and I reverted all the changes regards to it. No luck either. At the end this error was tied to Microsoft.UI.Xaml. If you want to submit app which uses it, you need to use at least version 2.6.1 (we were using 2.6.0). The issue here is that the pre-certification uses some "AppCompile.exe" which (seems) we don't have access to and you can see the logs from it just through Store Support team.

Comment: I know nothing about the "AppCompile.exe". I'll check if I could find something related. My suggestion is to keep in contact with the store support.